# linking radiobutton with functions in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this little issue with making functions run depending on the radiobutton selection as you can see in this code.

the purpose is to define which function to be executed when I press Calculate according to the radiobutton selection.

```
import tkinter as tk

master = tk.Tk()
tk.Label(master, text='Choose Color :').grid(row=0)


tk.Label(master, text='What Is The Number ? ').grid(row=2)
fdose = tk.Spinbox(master, from_ = 0, to = 60).grid(row=2, column=1)

def calculate():
    #this should take my input from the spinbox and add 10 to it if I choose Yellow
    #this should take my input from the spinbox and add 100 to it if I choose Green
    pass

v = tk.IntVar()
pen = tk.Radiobutton(master, text = 'Yellow',variable = v, value = 1).grid(row=0, column=1)
pen = tk.Radiobutton(master,text ='Green', variable = v, value = 2).grid(row=1, column=1)


but1 = tk.Button(master, text = 'Close', width = 20, bg = 'black', fg = 'red',activebackground = 'red', activeforeground = 'black', command = master.destroy)
but1.grid(row = 5, column = 1)

but2 = tk.Button(master, text = 'Calculate', width = 20, bg = 'black', fg = 'red',activebackground = 'red', activeforeground = 'black', command = calculate)
but2.grid(row = 5, column = 0)



master.mainloop()
```

Comment: What do you need help with? Everything looks set up properly.

Comment: I've edited the code now hope the problem is now clear. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Now your code doesn't have any radiobuttons at all, but your title still asks about radiobuttons. The question is even less clear than before.

Comment: Are you asking how to get the value of a radiobutton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the function `calculate` retrieves the value selected in the `radiobuttons`, and calls the appropriate `function`.

```
import tkinter as tk


master = tk.Tk()
tk.Label(master, text='Choose Color :').grid(row=0)


tk.Label(master, text='What Is The Number ? ').grid(row=2)
fdose = tk.Spinbox(master, from_=0, to=60).grid(row=2, column=1)

    
def do_yellow():
    print('doing the yellow thinghy')
    
def do_green():
    print('doing the green thinghy')

def calculate():
    """retrieves the value selected in the radiobuttons, and
    calls the appropriate function.
    """
    [do_yellow, do_green][int(v.get())-1]()

v = tk.IntVar()
pen = tk.Radiobutton(master, text='Yellow', variable=v, value=1)
pen.grid(row=0, column=1)
pen = tk.Radiobutton(master, text='Green', variable=v, value = 2)
pen.grid(row=1, column=1)

but1 = tk.Button(master, text='Close', width=20, bg='black', fg='red', activebackground='red', activeforeground='black', command=master.destroy)
but1.grid(row=5, column=1)

but2 = tk.Button(master, text='Calculate', width=20, bg='black', fg='red', activebackground='red', activeforeground='black', command=calculate)
but2.grid(row=5, column=0)

master.mainloop()
```

Comment: No worries - Please ask a new question if you have another problem that requires help to solve .